# How can a Category attribute be specified in a UWP custom control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, uwp

In WPF, when creating a custom control, you could cause your custom properties to be categorized in the Visual Studio/Blend Properties window by adding the following attribute:

```
[Category("MyCustomProperties")]    <---------
public bool MyProp
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MyPropProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropProperty, value); }
}
```

There is no CategoryAttribute in WinRT's System.ComponentModel namespace.

How is the same thing accomplished on the Universal Windows Platform?